# JavaScript: Why by selecting one radio button out of 2, values for both are returned?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, radio-button

I have two radio buttons, the second with an additional input field for value.
I am trying to determine which of the buttons is selected (if it is the second plus the value from the input field) and as a result change the value of a var.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src=".../jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<label>Select Workspace to display</label>
<input id="a-id" type="radio" name="re" value="a" checked>a
<input id="b-id" type="radio" name="re" value="b">b
<input id="input-value-id" type="text" placeholder="Insert Workspace ID"/>
</body>
<script>
var url;

//get value from radio button
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
  var value = $(this).val();
  console.log(value);
  if (value === 'b'){
    //get value from input field
    $("input").change(function () {
        var inputValue = $('#input-value-id').val();
        url = "testUrl/groups/" + inputValue + "/";  
        console.log(url);
    });
  }else if (value === 'a') {
    url = 'testUrl';
    console.log(url);
}
});
</script>
</html>
```

But the problem is when the first button (a) is selected, it returns the both url versions in console and the final is the b version (testUrl/groups//).

I cannot get where is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write only one event-handler for inputs and then inside that check if the radio button which is checked is `b` if yes and if the value of input is not null show that `url`

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var url;
$("input").change(function() {
  //check if checked value is b 
  if ($("[name=re]:checked").val() == "b") {
    var inputValue = $('#input-value-id').val();
    //if input is not empty
    if (inputValue != "") {
      url = "testUrl/groups/" + inputValue + "/";
      console.log(url);
    }
  } else if ($("[name=re]:checked").val() == "a") {
    //a
    url = 'testUrl';
    console.log(url);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Select Workspace to display</label>
<input id="a-id" type="radio" name="re" value="a" checked>a
<input id="b-id" type="radio" name="re" value="b">b
<input id="input-value-id" type="text" placeholder="Insert Workspace ID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code please replace the below code and try again

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {       
    var value = $(this).val();
    console.log(value);
    if (value === 'b') {
        //get value from input field
        $("b-id").click(function(){
            var inputValue = $('#input-value-id').val();
            url = "testUrl/groups/" + inputValue + "/";
            console.log(url);
        });
    } else {
        url = 'testUrl';
        console.log(url);
    }
});
```

You have used the "$("input").change(function ()" function, it called for both input values that way you will get both values on change.